# Proper way for setting indexes in query

Tags: mysql

I have got 2 tables.

*first* - table t_games (alias g)

```
column    type    
g_id      mediumint(8)    
t_id_1    smallint(5)    
t_id_2    smallint(5)    
g_team_1  varchar(50) 
g_team_2  varchar(50)
g_date    datetime    
g_live    tinyint(3)
```

Primary index is set on g_id field and there is additional composite index set on (t_id_1, t_id_2, g_date, g_live) fields.

*second* - table t_teams (aliases: t1 and t2)

```
column    type    
t_id      smallint(5)    
t_gw_name varchar(50)
gw_cid    tinyint(3)
```

Primary index is set on t_id.

*relation between tables* **updated**

There are two teams on each game. In table t_teams there are team's names. In t_games table I keep ID's related to the t_teams, to retreive name of each team taking part in the game. So to retreive a game ID with team's names:

```
SELECT g.g_id, t1.t_gw_name, t2.t_gw_name FROM t_games g
JOIN t_teams t1 ON (g.t_id_1 = t1.t_id)
JOIN t_teams t2 ON (g.t_id_2 = t2.t_id)
```

My SQL query:

```
SELECT g_id, t_id_1, t_id_2, g_team_1, g_team_2, g_date, g_live, t1.t_gw_name AS t_gw_name_1, t1.gw_cid AS gw_cid_1, t2.t_gw_name AS t_gw_name_2, t2.gw_cid AS gw_cid_2
FROM t_games g
JOIN t_teams t1 ON (t_id_1 = t1.t_id) JOIN t_teams t2 ON (t_id_2 = t2.t_id)
WHERE g.g_date < "2013-07-24 20:00:00" AND g.g_live < 2`
```

And after explain I get:
`

```
1     SIMPLE            g       ALL         t_id_1        NULL    NULL    NULL       16     Using where
1     SIMPLE            t1     eq_ref       PRIMARY     PRIMARY     2     t_id_1     1     
1     SIMPLE            t2     eq_ref       PRIMARY     PRIMARY     2     t_id_2     1`
```

I tried many combination of indexing the table, but I can't get rid of the ALL scan.

Comment: What is `g`? And how do the other tables relate to it?

Comment: OK. Are you sure you need all these columns? t_id_1    smallint(5)    
t_id_2    smallint(5)    
g_team_1  varchar(50) 
g_team_2  varchar(50)

Comment: An index is not a magic bullet, and it's not always the fastest option. ["Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large percentage of the rows in the table. (In this case, a table scan is likely to be much faster because it requires fewer seeks.)"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I figured out that adding g_team_1 and g_team_2 to the select is causing the problem. When I remove that fields from select statement, the query and indexes works fine. Why?

Comment: Unless you have determined that the lack of that index is causing a bottleneck, stop worrying about it. Your table has only 16 rows, MySQL's query analyzer is not *completely* incompetent. **Optimize this query when you know it is the problem, not before.**

Comment: Thank you. I thought that if full scan is made right now, it also will be made later with more records. I forgot about that number of records does matter.

Answer (score 1):

In your case (for the query you've shown) you only need an index that covers a *single* column `g_date`.

Whereas you see `ALL` because:

1. There are only 16 rows in the table (?)
2. You're selecting more than ~30% of rows of the table

On both cases it's easier to scan all the table rather than use index.

So to check that `g_date` index works:

1. Fill the `t_games` table with something like 1000 rows
2. Perform a query that would return about 10 rows from `t_games` table

PS:

1. composite index `(g_date, g_live)` won't work because you have range comparison for both columns
2. single `g_live` won't <s>work</s> be very effective because it's a low cardinality for that column

Comment: As I said to DCoder, I forgot about that number of records does matter. You're right. I'll test the query with more records in the table.